# How to get the best solution every time it is changed (at every step)?

Tags: optaplanner

I want to get the best solution at every step that it is changed. I implemented the "bestSolutionChanged" event but it is only triggered at the end of a phase.I want to do this so i can take the state of the planning variables and keep track of what the changes are and where did it improve.

Is this normal for it to trigger the event at the end of a phase or i am doing something wrong in the implementation?

Comment: In Local Search, bestSolutionChanged is triggered at every step that improves the score. in ConstructionHeuristics it's not because the best solution cloning needed to support that heavily impacts performance.